# iPad landscape right view clipped off on load

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

We have an iOS app that simply launches a webview that opens our actual app, which is just a web app. However, if I open the app in landscape right on an iPad, it is the correct orientation, but it clips off a third of the right side of the screen. Essentially, it is setting the view as portrait in a landscape view, so everything is shifted to the left.

If I open the app in any other position, it is fine and it seamlessly switches between portrait or landscape in any direction. I am just jumping into the code and am not an iOS expert, so I'm not sure on all of the different things to try, but I will show the code I'm working in and changes I've tried.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: portalUrl]];

        _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        _webView.delegate = self;
        [_webView loadRequest:request];
        _webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.view addSubview:_webView];
        [self showBusyIndicator];
    });
}

// I've tried different combinations here, and none of them seemed to help
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
   self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

Also, I checked the .plist, and it has all orientations listed there. I know that the problem revolves around when you open in right landscape, it sets the size of the screen to portrait, but I don't know the culprit.

I've been trolling the internets for a solution, but I can't find anything that fixes it (I'm probably not searching for the right thing...) If it's helpful, I'm testing on a 7.1 iOS iPad.

Comment: 1) The `autoresizingMask` you set for `self.view` in `viewDidLoad` is the default. So it's not needed. 2) No need to set the frame of `self.view` to its current frame in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. And you should call `super` if your override the method. 3) The web view's frame should be set to `self.view.bounds`, not `self.view.frame`.

Comment: @rmaddy Do you mean the `self.view.frame` in the `initWithFrame` should be set to `self.view.bounds`.

Comment: Yes. A child view's frame needs to be relative to its parent frame which means you should use `bounds`, not `frame`.

Comment: Changing `self.view.frame` to `self.view.bounds` did the trick. Thanks.